# How do I compensate holidays - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, date-range

Let's say I have a data frame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ending Date': [Timestamp('2019-12-08 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-12-08 00:00:00')], 'FName': ['Jon', 'Bob'], 'LName': ['Doe', 'Smith'], 'Starting Date': ['2019-09-29', '2019-09-29']})
```

---

```
  Ending Date FName  LName Starting Date
0  2019-12-07   Jon    Doe    2019-09-28
1  2019-12-07   Bob  Smith    2019-09-28
```

As you can see, the Ending Date columns is always 10 weeks ahead of the Starting Date, however, I have a list of holidays:

```
holidays = pd.Series([Timestamp('2019-09-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-10-05 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-10-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-10-26 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-12-21 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-12-28 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-01-04 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-01-25 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-02-29 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-04-04 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-05-02 00:00:00')])
```

Therefore, I want to "compensate" the holidays, so I want to get every Saturday of the range between the Starting Date and the Ending Date that's in the holiday Series to be counted, and add the n (the count) weeks to the Ending Date, and, if any of the added weeks are holidays, compensate them as well, and so on...

I tried:

```
df['Ending Date'] = df['Ending Date'] + pd.Timedelta(weeks=10 + pd.date_range(df['Starting Date'], df['Ending Date']).isin(holidays).sum())
```

But an error of:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert input [0    2019-09-28
1    2019-09-28
Name: Starting Date, dtype: object] of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to Timestamp
```

Is raised.

Desired output:

```
  Ending Date FName  LName Starting Date
0  2020-01-18   Jon    Doe    2019-09-28
1  2020-01-18   Bob  Smith    2019-09-28
```

Comment: What is expected output here?

Comment: Can you just use business day calculations in `pandas` (see [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#custom-business-days)) rather than doing the calculations yourself?

Comment: @jezrael Could you find an answer?

Comment: I dont understand it, so now not :(

Comment: @jezrael let me show you the loop so 10 weeks from 28th of september is 7th of december, but in the range, it contains three holidays so the ending date should be extended by 3 weeks, so then it will be 28th of december, but there is two more new holidays in the range, so the ending date should be extended by two weeks, January 11th, then there is one more holiday added, so plus one week will be January 18th, get it now?

Comment: What is number of rows? Because seems need loops for each row, so solution is slow :(

Comment: @jezrael Around 60, i don't mind the performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that both *Starting Date* and *Ending Date* should be of *datetime64[ns]*
type. If they are not, convert them with *pd.to_datetime*.

I noticed that you use only Saturday dates, so your case is something like
we had a *business week* including only one working day in a calendar week,
namely only Saturday.

Then, to do your task, it is quite easy if we make use of **Custom Business
Calendar**, with user defined holiday dates.

Start with defining *CustomBusinessDay* offset, including your hoilday list:

```
my_bday = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(holidays=holidays, weekmask='Sat')
```

Then, to compute the date *n* business days (actually - also weeks) ahead
from a given date *dat*, we should use formula: `dat + 10 * my_bday`.

So in your case (source data in *Starting Date* column and the result to be
saved in *Ending Date*), run:

```
df['Ending Date'] = df['Starting Date'].apply(lambda dat: dat + 10 * my_bday)
```